# Should I use a question mark when the second independent clause of my sentence is not a question?

Tags: punctuation, question-mark

Is it appropriate to use a question mark at the end of a compound sentence where the first independent clause is a question but the second is a statement? For example:

> Do you want attribution for that quotation, because I'm definitely sharing it and want to know if I should give you credit?

or

> Do you want attribution for that quotation, because I'm definitely sharing it and want to know if I should give you credit.

I suppose this could work, but it's a little niche, as the second clause might not always be appropriate for a parenthetical.

> Do you want attribution for that quotation (because I'm definitely sharing it and want to know if I should give you credit)?

Comment: I would write it as the parenthetical.

Comment: Use two sentences.  End the first one with a question mark. Start the second with _Because_. You'll feel no pain; only your English teacher will feel it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the second statement doesn't ask a question, I would consider writing it as a separate sentence:

> Do you want attribution for that quotation? Because I'm definitely sharing it, and I want to know if I should give you credit.

It's clearer that way.

Comment: Do you want attribution for that quotation? because I'm definitely sharing it, and I want to know if I should give you credit.

Comment: Why did you change the "b" in "because" from upper to lower case?

Comment: Instead of a new sentence, perhaps just replace the comma with a question mark in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: I rolled back the change.  The core of Thursagen's answer was to make it two sentences, so your suggestion of lowercasing the *b* to keep it one sentence isn't just a small tweak, but rather a complete change.  I'd suggest making it its own answer.

Comment: @Dusty Me too. An anonymous user's suggestion [was approved by reviewers](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/241207), and I disagree with the edit.

Answer (score 0):

According to this site I found: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/question.htm , the first way you phrased it is suppose to be correct.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: And yep, the linked page changed.